# Why is my express.js not piping to my backend server port?

Tags: node.js, express, ports

I'm using Express.JS/Node to host my web server. It works fine, using this:

```
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8090, function () {

    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Express server listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

I am able to navigate to `localhost:8090` and my website launches.

I also launch my backend server with `php -S localhost:8088`.

This is fine and I can make api calls as `localhost:8088/api/auth/check` and it returns my test value.

However, I am trying to call this from my website and it continues to use port 8090. (AJAX with url: '`/api/auth/check`')

I thought that I could pipe the request using the following:

```
var apiUrl = process.env.apiUrl || 'http://localhost:8088/api';

app.use('/api', function(req, res) {
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

It doesn't work - I get an ErrorConnectionRefused and my chrome developer tools network tab shows `http://localhost:8090/api/auth/check`.

What's most odd is that this did work previously - the network tab showed localhost:8090 and the api call, but the specifics said hostname localhost:8088 - and I could preview the response showing the test value in the developer console. I could also navigate via URL to `http://localhost:8090/api/auth/check` and it gave the proper response.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It looks like the URL you are requesting is `http://localhost:8088/api/api/auth/check`, because `apiUrl` contains the `/api` path already. Aside from that, it's unclear to me what exactly is generating the _connection refused_ error (your Express app or Chrome).

Comment: Hmm, I do a console.log on the "url" variable within app.use and it returns localhost:8088/api/auth/check.

Comment: Okay so I guess that `process.env.apiUrl` is set in that case (and the hardcoded value isn't being used).

Comment: The hardcoded value is being used. apiUrl is the hardcoded value. Req.url ends up omitting the /api at the beginning (it is only /auth/check). I believe this is the functionality of app.use - it matches on the first argument ('/api').

Comment: Oh duh, you're absolutely right!